# SQL Query to return highest dif and associated username

Tags: mysql, sql

new to SQL and stackoverflow.

I have been trying to piece together a query to return values from two columns based on the highest dif between rows in one of the columns.

I have a mysql table in wordpress:

id  userid  username  week  jumpheight  goalheight...... and some others.

This is for a four week training program.  I need to query to find the highest jumpheight increase between weeks 1 and 2, (and then week 1 and 3, and week 1 and 4 - as separate queries).    I need to return the the value of the highest positive difference between Week 1 and 2 as well as the username for the person associated with that value.

This is what I have been able to piece together:

```
SELECT username,
       SUM(CASE week When '2' THEN jumpheight
                     WHEN '1' THEN -jumpheight
           END) AS value
FROM blitzclipper
GROUP BY userid
```

It returns the correct difference jumpheight value for the highest difference however it returns 1)the highest negative value as well as positive and 2) the first username in the username column rather than the username for the person associated to the highest difference.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  thnx

Comment: Please show sample data for the `blitzclipper` table, and ideally the output you would want to get.

Comment: You usually GROUP BY the selected columns that are not arguments to a set function. In your case `GROUP BY username`.

Comment: @jarlh - mysql is bit flexible in this respect (I think of it as a mis-feature).

Comment: @GurV, newer MySQL versions are stricter and will return an error if the GROUP BY is invalid (unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: @jarlh - Agreed, but people again disable it for some reason. I've seen people asking questions for newer version of MySQL and still doing this. They should've just remove this disable once and for all. :)